# Java.awt.* not in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-storm, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

Is there any way to import following in BlackBerry JDE 5.0 or in eclipse with BlackBerry JDE 4.7 ?

```
import java.awt.Canvas;

import java.awt.Color;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import java.awt.Image;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
```

I need to implement it for Barcode Reader in BlackBerry. For barcode Reader, I download the rVision.jar & import it.

If there is any solution or alternative solution then please suggest me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the open source project [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)? Check it out. They even provide the full source code for a BlackBerry client that uses their library.

Comment: Thanks for giving information...It is good source for Barcode Reader.

Answer (score 3):

No, AWT is not part of the API on the BlackBerry.  However, you do have both the J2ME and RIM APIs that are equivalent in functionality to what you get from above.  Just search around in the JavaDocs, and you'll find them.

However, you will need to modify the library you are trying to use, so that it uses those alternative graphics APIs instead.